# Expectation of function of independent random variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I see that *Mathematica* added some random variable features in the last 5 years, are there some nice tutorials for finding expectations of functions of random variables?

In particular, I have `x1` and `x2` are sampled independently from $\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ where

$$\Sigma = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & k \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Then I have a random variable $y$ defined as

$$y = \frac{<x1, x2>}{\|x1\|\|x2\|}$$

and I need to find $E[y]$ and $E[y^2]$. Basically it's finding how the angle between two random vectors depends on their covariance matrix.

Comment: Can't we argue that $E[y]=0$ from first principles?

Comment: yes, E[y] looks like 0

Comment: For every condition where there is a positive value of ${{\bf x}_1 \cdot {\bf x}_2 \over \| {\bf x}_1 \| \ \| {\bf x}_2 \|}$, there is a condition with the corresponding negative value.

Comment: You might be better asking on the Mathematics site, as this is not really specific to Mathematica.  I think that this might have a solution that is well known to the right audience.

Comment: Here is how you'd express this in *Mathematica*:  `Expectation[x1.x2/(Norm[x1] Norm[x2]), {x1, x2} \[Distributed] 
  MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{1, 0}, {0, k}}]]` and likewise for the $E[y^2]$ case.  Unfortunately, *Mathematica* cannot solve these in this form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason, *Mathematica* can handle the problem when represented as one-dimensional distributions, which is allowed given your covariance matrix is diagonal.

---

**$E[y]$**

```
Assuming[k > 0,
 Expectation[
   (x1x x2x + x1y x2y)/((x1x^2 + x1y^2) (x2x^2 + x2y^2))^(1/2),
   {x1x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1],
    x1y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, k],
    x2x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1],
    x2y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, k]}]
 ]
```

$0$ (as it should, based on symmetry arguments)

---

**$E[y^2]$**

*Mathematica* has difficulty solving for the *general* case when $k>1$ and $k<1$, but can do each individually (and they give the same answer):

```
Assuming[k > 1, 
 Expectation[(x1x x2x + x1y x2y)^2/((x1x^2 + x1y^2) (x2x^2 + x2y^2)), 
  {x1x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
   x1y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[k]], 
   x2x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
   x2y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[k]]}]]
```

$\frac{k+1}{(\sqrt{k}+1)^2}$

and

```
Assuming[0 < k < 1, 
 Expectation[(x1x x2x + x1y x2y)^2/((x1x^2 + x1y^2) (x2x^2 + x2y^2)), 
  {x1x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
   x1y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[k]], 
   x2x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
   x2y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[k]]}]]
```

$\frac{k+1}{(\sqrt{k}+1)^2}$.

---

An explicit check for the case $k=1$:

```
Expectation[(x1x x2x + x1y x2y)^2/((x1x^2 + x1y^2) (x2x^2 + x2y^2)), 
    {x1x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
     x1y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
     x2x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1], 
     x2y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]}]
```

${1 \over 2}$, which agrees with the general case.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. That expression seems weird though. If you plug in values of k close to 1 it gives implausibly large results

Comment: I think *Mathematica* had problems solving for both the cases when $k>1$ and $k<1$.  The new answer is remarkably simple!

Comment: thanks, that works. Actually it works with multinormal too and seems a bit cleaner, posted that example for posterity

Comment: it seems they still haven't made it possible to use subscripts in variable names...

Comment: I think you need to use `Sqrt[k]` in place of `k` to match the original question (which has the variance being `k` rather than the standard deviation being `k`).

Comment: @Jim Baldwin:  Ah yes... thanks.  I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
normal := MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, ( {{1, 0}, {0, k} } )];
x := {x1, x2};
y := {y1, y2};
vars := {x \[Distributed] normal, y \[Distributed] normal};
Assuming[0 < k < 1, Expectation[(x.y/(Norm[x] Norm[y]))^2, vars]]
```

Result

$$\frac{k+1}{\left(\sqrt{k}+1\right)^2}$$

Comment: I tried your code Assuming[0<k, ...] and got different answers for $k<1$ and $k>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
f[k_] := MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, ({{1, 0}, {0, k}})];
rv[k_, n_] := 
 Mean[(#1.#2)^2/(#1.#1 #2.#2) & @@@ RandomVariate[f[k], {n, 2}]]
vis[n_] := 
 Show[Plot[(1 + k)/(1 + Sqrt[k])^2, {k, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> All], 
  ListPlot[Table[{j, rv[j, n]}, {j, 0.01, 1, 0.01}]], 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, 
  GridLines -> {None, {1/2}}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"n= ", n}], 
  ImageSize -> 200]
Grid[Partition[vis /@ {100, 1000, 10000, 100000}, 2]]
```

[image]